# How can I fix the number of neurons of encoder/decoder?

Tags: tensorflow, encoding, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm going through the tutorial : 
https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

Especially in the `Deep autoencoder` section, the code doesn't work.

```
encoding_dim = 32
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
print('autoencoder layers:', autoencoder.layers)
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)


encoded_input = Input(shape = (encoding_dim,)) 
print('encoded_input', encoded_input)
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
print('decoder_layer:', autoencoder.layers[-1])
print('decoded:', decoder_layer(encoded_input))
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adadelta', loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
```

When I run the code as it is, I run into the error.

```
  File "simple_sparsity_deep_autoencoder.py", line 68, in <module>
    print('decoded:', decoder_layer(encoded_input))
  File "C:\Users\sonogi-y\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\textbook\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 440, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\sonogi-y\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\textbook\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 352, in assert_input_compatibility
    ' but got shape ' + str(x_shape))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_6: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 128 but got shape (None, 32)
```

I guess the input node number doesn't match the decoder layer.
How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: I am very much confused by what you're trying to achieve here. `decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]      print('decoded:', decoder_layer(encoded_input))`. You are essentially trying to feed in an input that has 784 features (`encoded_input`) to a layer which accepts 128 features (`decoder_layer`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for my poor explanation. I just wanna put encoded features into a decoder with ```decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))``` and input is ```encoded_input``` which should have 32 features and output ``` decoder_layer(encoded_input)``` better have the shape of the last layer of the model ``` decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded) ```. How can I fix to make it work??

Comment: Still not very clear what you want. Are you trying to have two separate models (encoder and decoder)? And then get the output of the encoder. Then feed that output to the decoder as an input?

Comment: yeah, I'm following the tutorial attached above and I guess they create encoder and decoder each to show what happens after encoded (to show the important features after encoding), and combine them to create autoencoder model. but it doesn't work...